# Threading with pyqt5 gui, Display loading gif while processing

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have something like this in my code, I want to display my loading gif while waiting to finished my process. I tried this threading that I found, but I keep getting this error saying:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

here is my code sample

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QSize, QRunnable, 
QThreadPool, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
import main2 as main_framework

class Worker(QRunnable):
   def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Worker, self).__init__()
       self.fn = fn
       self.args = args
       self.kwargs = kwargs

   @pyqtSlot()
   def run(self):
       self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

class Ui_Login(QtWidgets.QDialog, QPushButton):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Ui_Login, self).__init__()
       uic.loadUi("gui/loginpage.ui", self)
       self.frame_loadinggif.setVisible(False)
       self.btn_signin.clicked.connect(self.signin)
       self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.signout)
       self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

   def task(self):
       print("in")
       form = main_framework.Ui_MainWindow()
       form.show()
       self.btn_signin.setEnabled(True)
       self.hide()

   def loadinggif(self):
       self.frame_loadinggif.setVisible(True)
       self.gif = QMovie("images/ajax-loader.gif", QByteArray(), self)
       self.lbl_loading_gif.setMovie(self.gif)
       self.gif.setScaledSize(QSize().scaled(25, 25, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
       self.gif.start()

   def signin(self):
       print("processing")
       self.loadinggif()
       worker = Worker(self.task)
       self.threadpool.start(worker)
       self.btn_signin.setEnabled(False)

   def signout(self):
       print("out")
       sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ui = Ui_Login()
   ui.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What is your processing?

Comment: Okay by definition you cannot put anything based on QtWidgets as well as some things based on QtGui within anything but the MainThread.

Comment: for now there is no processing happening, I just want to know how to run a function in the background while the loading still spinning, then change some ui to what I need.

Comment: I tried to remove this from the task method form = main_framework.Ui_MainWindow()
       form.show() and now it works but how can I show the next window I want to show?